# Click detection not working?

Tags: java, applet, mouseevent

So here is the entire file I am using, and in desperation, I put the x and y to be defined in every event but I still get nothing.. this is a multi-class project, where should I do `addMouseListener()`? and why isnt this picking up the event? (note: the printing of the coordinates in `run()` works.) This is an applet project and the applet works fine just doesnt register this event.

```
public class ClickCheck implements Runnable, java.awt.event.MouseListener {
public int x, y;

public ClickCheck() {

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) {

    x = ev.getX();
    y = ev.getY();
    System.out.println(x + "," + y);
}

public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) {
    x = ev.getX();
    y = ev.getY();
    System.out.println(x + "," + y);
}

public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) {
    x = ev.getX();
    y = ev.getY();
    System.out.println(x + "," + y);
}

public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) {
    x = ev.getX();
    y = ev.getY();
    System.out.println(x + "," + y);
}

public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) {
    x = ev.getX();
    y = ev.getY();
    System.out.println(x + "," + y);
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(x + "," + y);

}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code where you call addMouseListener. If you're not sure where to call it, add the listener to the graphical component you expect users to click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a `MouseListener` to the main window/panel area of your applet you would add this to your applet `init()` method:

```
public void init()
{
   addMouseListener(new ClickCheck());
   ...
```

Also it's very unusual to have `Thread` included in your `MouseListener`. The thread itself will print out co-ordinates & exit immediately.

Comment: thank you sooo much. I had `addMouseListener(player1)` which was a variable.. I guess I was kinda close lol.. waiting 6 minutes to accept your answer. lol. EDIT: yea I removed that after I realized how useless it was, thanks again.